# Wireless connection with an Atheros AR9285 keeps dropping every 20 minutes

Tags: wireless, atheros

There are other questions on this but none have been taken very far in their analysis.

I get disconnects very often - sometimes every 20 mins or so, but sometimes even every few minutes.

The way I have been getting around it is to disconnect from the Wifi connection and reconnect - and then it works fine again until the next disconnect.

I am running Ubuntu 11.04 on an ASUS A52F. Can anyone help me please?

EDIT: My investigations have led me to believe this might be the router, as the same problem is duplicated on my gf's HTC smartphone. Any ideas of how to solve?

Output of `lspci | grep -i net`

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01) 04:00.5 
Ethernet controller: JMicron Technology Corp. 
JMC250 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 03)
```

Comment: What Chipset? `lspci | grep -i net`

Comment: 02:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
04:00.5 Ethernet controller: JMicron Technology Corp. JMC250 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 03)

Answer (score 1):

Try this command,

```
sudo dhclient -v
```

There shouldn't be any errors. My successful output looks like this,

```
Listening on LPF/eth3/00:e0:52:ce:a0:f6
Sending on   LPF/eth3/00:e0:52:ce:a0:f6
Listening on LPF/eth2/00:50:43:00:f5:c7
Sending on   LPF/eth2/00:50:43:00:f5:c7
Listening on LPF/eth0/20:cf:30:4f:60:43
Sending on   LPF/eth0/20:cf:30:4f:60:43
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on eth3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.11.100 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.107 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPACK of 192.168.1.107 from 192.168.1.1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
bound to 192.168.1.107 -- renewal in 40407 seconds.
```

Comment: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.1.1-P1
Copyright 2004-2010 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/wlan0/74:f0:6d:7c:11:42
Sending on   LPF/wlan0/74:f0:6d:7c:11:42
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.0.11 from 192.168.0.1
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.11 on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPACK of 192.168.0.11 from 192.168.0.1
bound to 192.168.0.11 -- renewal in 1767 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf

sudo modprobe -rfv ath9k
sudo modprobe -v ath9k`
```

And make sure that your router is set on WPA2 encryption.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a DHCP lease time with a router/DHCP router. Check this file
and see what the renewal times are.

```
 vi /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases
```

A lease looks like this.

```
lease {
  interface "eth0";
  fixed-address 192.168.1.107;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option dhcp-lease-time 86400;
  option routers 192.168.1.1;
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.1.1;
  option domain-name-servers 208.67.222.222,208.67.220.220,8.8.8.8,4.2.2.2,68.94.156.1;
  option dhcp-renewal-time 43200;
  option dhcp-rebinding-time 75600;
  option host-name "bust0ut5";
  renew 0 2012/03/04 00:29:06;
  rebind 0 2012/03/04 10:44:45;
  expire 0 2012/03/04 13:44:45;
}
```

Comment: My dhclient.leases file is empty! :(

Comment: lease {
  interface "wlan0";
  fixed-address 192.168.0.11;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option time-offset 0;
  option dhcp-lease-time 3600;
  option routers 192.168.0.1;
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option domain-name-servers 194.168.4.100,194.168.8.100;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.0.1;
  option default-ip-ttl 64;
  renew 3 2012/04/04 11:45:55;
  rebind 3 2012/04/04 12:08:58;
  expire 3 2012/04/04 12:16:28;

Comment: My investigations have led me to believe this might be the router, as the same problem is duplicated on my gf's HTC smartphone. Any ideas of how to solve?

Comment: If you can access the router, change the lease time to 36000. We had the same problem in the dormitory, so I changed the leasetime for the smart phones to 24h. (We separate normal pc/laptop from smart phones)